# Using ltrim(); to take away '0's from the start of my users input

Tags: php

I ask for a user to input 4 numbers or letter from 1 - 9 and a-f.

i then take these numbers and letters and `str_replace` them with 4 byte values.

So if the user inputs `00FF`, the value would be `0000 0000 1111 1111`, as `0000` is the 4 byte value of `0` and `1111` is the 4 byte value of `F`.

I want to get rid of any leading `'0's` from the total collection of 4 byte values.

I have tried using the below code to get rid of the 0's from the start of it.

```
$hexvalue2 = ltrim($hexvalue,'0');
echo $hexvalue2;
```

However, this is not working, when looking at PHP.net as far as my knowledge goes this seems correct, but obviously its not.

Can anyone tell me where i am going wrong please? or perhaps suggest an alternative?

Thank you

Comment: yes i kno, can you offer any alternative methods then?

Comment: `$hex`/`$hexvalue`? And what output do you get?

Comment: What is it printing out?

Comment: refer to updated question. i was very vague before. apologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
<?
$h = 0x00001111;

$h = ltrim(dechex($h),"0");

echo $h;
?>
```

Output: `1111`

Note the `dechex` to get a string.

Comment: because i modified my code to fit in with your suggestion. i can unaccept if you like?

Comment: That's okay. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

I would modify the function that converts `00FF` to `0000 0000 1111 1111`, so that it doesn't add `0000` for occurances of 0 at the beginning of the input string.

```
<?php
function convert4byte($in) {
    $in = preg_replace('/^0+(.*)/', '$1', $in);
    $out = '';
    $i = 0;
    do {
        $out .= sprintf('%04d', decbin(hexdec($in[$i])));
        $i++;
    } while ($i < strlen($in) && $out .= ' ');
    return $out;
}
$str = '00FF';
echo convert4byte($str);
?>
```

http://codepad.org/eCmhOpAO

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```
$hexvalue = '00001111';
$hexvalue2 = ltrim($hexvalue,'0');
echo $hexvalue2;
//prints 1111
```

Make sure that `$hexvalue` is a string, not any other type.

Comment: refer to updated question, i was very vague before. apologies